# React Native listview does not refresh on row edit

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I am having trouble with the listview not refreshing it's datasource unless I leave the page and come back.My listview is inside of a NavigatorIOS component.

Every post I have read sais to refresh the datasource with a new object. It works fine when I remove/add something from the datasource, however when I want to only edit a row from the datasource it does not refresh the view.

This code does not work

```
editMessage(title, message, messageIndex, replyIndex){
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    var newData =  [];
    newData = this.state.data.slice();
    newData[messageIndex].replies[replyIndex].title= title;
    newData[messageIndex].replies[replyIndex].message= message;
    this.setState({data: newData});
    this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(newData)});
},
```

however a sample like this works fine

```
    removeMessage(index){
    console.log(index);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    var newData = this.state.data;
    newData.splice(index, 1);


    this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(newData)});

},
```

edit: I have already tried copy by value, it still does not work.

`newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
        newData[messageIndex].replies[replyIndex].title= title;
        newData[messageIndex].replies[replyIndex].message= message;
        this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(newData)});
        this.setState({data: newData});`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is a by reference error on this.state.. Since you are changing properties on the object in an array of objects that will have pointers back to the original this.state array. if you then set that array as the original state, it would think it is the same array as you are only modifying the objects in the array. From the Mozilla docs on array.slice

"For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: I have already tried `newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data));` after modifiying this.state.data, still no change. I was under the impression that the line of code copied by value

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in my logic, children don't refresh even though the state is updated.

currently the parent data source looks like this

```
[
 {
  index: 
  author: 
  title: 
  message: 
  replies: [{
              author: 
              title: 
              message:
            }]
 }
]
```

The child component is only using the replies array as the datasource

```
  replies: [{
              author: 
              title: 
              message:
            }]
```

Why does it matter though? When I change the parent state, the child's datasource also changes because it is using the same datasource. But it does not refresh the page. I have to update the the childs datasource as well even though the parent has changed the state.

The parent has this code

```
editMessage(title, message, messageIndex, replyIndex){

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

this.state.data[messageIndex].replies[replyIndex].title= title;
this.state.data[messageIndex].replies[replyIndex].message= message;

this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.data)});
this.setState({data: this.state.data});
```

},

and the child has this code

```
editMessage(title, message, replyIndex){

this.props.editMessage(title, message, this.props.pushEvent.index ,replyIndex); 
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.replies)});
```

},